# Difference Between この and これ

Tags: meaning

Both seem to means "this."

Answer (score 6):

They do mean "this" but...

In English we can use words like "this" in two ways.

1. This is beautiful
2. This country is beautiful

The Japanese language uses これ for 1. and この for 2.

この needs to be followed by a noun to become one and これ is an standalone noun.

この＋NOUN = This NOUN (as in: この国が美しい, This country is beautiful)

これ = This (as in: これが美しい, This is beautiful)

Answer (score -2):

Kore is used to indicate an object that you don't know the name of.

Kono is the opposite: it's used to indicate an object that you know the name of.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I would say that it's true that you can talk about things you don't know the name of with "kore", but it's not a defining or limiting characteristic. If I'm holding a bag and say "chotto kore mottete" (Hold this for a bit), it doesn't imply I don't know the word for "bag" in Japanese.

Comment: Yeah I realized that shortly after posting the response. The correct response is: kore means this and sore means that